# What would be the correct way to say this sentence using "amico"?

Tags: articles, gender

[image]

……………………………………………………………………………….
Just the image below, it seems to think that using amico instead of amica was incorrect but I don’t see any other gendered words in the sentence. How else would you word the sentence if you were saying amico?

Answer (score 3):

The actual error is that there is the apostrofe in **un'amico*. The masculine form is *un amico*, the feminine one is *un'amica*, because the latter is an elision for *una amica*, while *un* is an article in its own right: compare with *un gatto* / *una gatta*.

That said, Duolingo isn't always reliable: sometimes it knows one correct answer and rejects different ones, even though they are correct as well.

Answer (score 3):

The English word *friend* doesn’t tell the gender and without context you don’t know whether to translate it into

> un amico

or

> un’amica

On the other hand, writing **un’amico* is certainly wrong. Without context both sentences

> Laura ha un amico di Roma

and

> Laura ha un’amica di Roma

would be correct.

Apparently, the Duolingo algorithm saw the apostrophe and suggested feminine. Or maybe it associated feminine to Laura, as if she couldn’t have male friends. You might try and see what it would answer with

> Laura ha un amica di Roma

(which is wrong because the apostrophe is missing). Another attempt might be to input “Mario has a friend from Rome” and see what happens.

In any case, it was correct in telling you that the sentence you wrote is incorrect.

<sub>Note: I restrict the context to dual gender, because going deeply into such matters is not the object of learning the basics of Italian with software such as Duolingo.</sub>